# Flutter Gesture detector onTap sound not working

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

Why flutter `GestureDetector` doesn't make the tap (or click) sound like on the `IconButton` widget? Is there any way to implement that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Feedback.forTap(context)` . It provides platform-specific feedback like click sound or vibration. Add to the inside `onTap` callback of `GestureDetector`

Answer (score -1):

IconBotton has itself an onTap callback you can use that instead of a gesture detector.

Comment: Your point makes sense. But GestureDetector has more features like       longtap, double tap etc...